# Is it possible to extract part of an object and move it

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I have an object which is a single mesh (is that the correct term? - I can only select the entire object) and I would like to actually raise the height of part of the object to match the rest.
It is a single building and for whatever reason, maybe a mistake, it is lower than it should be. The author created the object about 13 years ago and I have not been able to get responses from emails sent to him.
The object is below and I have circled the building which is at the wrong height and which I would like to raise the height (Z axis) about 0.3 metres).
How would I do this?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: go in Edit mode and see if it's a separate mesh, select it with L and move it? And you can separate it as a separate object if you press P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the entire pier/building combination in *Object* mode
- Enter edit mode
- Deselect all.
- switch to vertex select mode. (This isn't necessary but it makes the next part easier to explain.)
- hover over a vertex that is part of the building you want to raise.
- *Island Select* (shortcut <kbd>L</kbd>)

At this point all of the vertices of the building should be selected if it is actually detached from the other parts of the deck.  If more of the object is selected, see below. You now have two choices:

1. You can leave the object intact.  In this case, just move the building on the Z axis until it is at the right height.  (Shortcut <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>)
2. You can separate the building into a different object using the *Part* menu.  Open the part menu (Shortcut <kbd>P</kbd>) and choose *Selection*.  This will make the building a separate object.  Once that's done:

- return to *Object* mode
- select the building.  (This is a good time to give it its own name).
- use the right mouse button menu and choose *Set Origin* -> *Origin to Geometry*
- move the building on the Z axis to the correct position.

---

If *Island Select* selected more than the building, that means it is attached to the mesh.  At this point, before you can part the building you have to separate it from the mesh. Start by deselecting all.

Examine each place where the building is attached to the rest of the mesh.  Either it is attached by an unnecessary edge, or it shares a vertex with the rest of the object.

- If it's an unnecessary edge, select the edge and delete it.
- If it's a shared vertex, select the vertex and *Rip Vertices*. (Shortcut <kbd>V</kbd>.)

Once you have completely separated the building you can go back to the first part of my answer to fix the elevation.

Comment: Thanks Marty, I followed your instructions (as best I could and feel I have made a mistake) but when I 'hovered' over a vertex and pressed L (shortcut) it only seemed to select a FACE (see image added to the original post). Note where my cursor is highlighting Vertex Select which was selected. Also note that there are 'spaces' between the building and everything else which should make it easier ie the last part of you method unnecessary. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Added later. That gave me an idea so I chose FACE select and (holding down shift key) selected every face and was able to raise the building (G + Z keys). Thanks though for giving me the right idea. I did notice though, that when selecting faces every separate face consisted of two faces with a diagonal line across the face (joining vertexes)n so I have so select two faces for every visible face. That (diagonal line) probably came from when I imported a .glTF image extracted from the original (Flight Simulator) model. I have added another image to my original post where you can see what I mean

Comment: @JohnArnold You managed to find one possibility I didn't think of: The building is made of more than one mesh.  Your approach works well.  The alternative would have been to keep hovering over unselected vertices and pressing L until you finally had all the faces you wanted.

Comment: Thanks be to you though for making me consider using something else which I have done in the past but never considered as I didn't realise I could select just part of a single mesh.